# Add value to TextView?

Tags: android, textview, addition

I have a TextView where is set my budget. For example, 100$. When I press a button I introduce a new value, for example 40$, and I want to display in my TextView the addition of 100$ (initial value from TextView) and 40$(what I introduced). That's mean 140$.How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double newValue = 40;
String txtOld = txtView.getText();
txtOld.replace("$","");
double oldValue = Double.parseDouble(txtOld);
txtView.setText((oldValue + newValue)+"$");
```

Comment: If the `TextView` contained '100$', this would result in '100$40'. This is concatenation, not addition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the settext property of the textview to set the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You need set an event for that, that is called on change value. After that, you need make a new int variable that receives *only* the value. I suggest you don't work with "$", but if it is need, you need cut out it. After, you add 100 to int, convert to String again and apply on TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to keep track of the current amount (without the currency symbol)

```
int totalAmount = 100;
```

then set it as the text in your TextView

```
textView.setText(totalAmount + "$");
```

when a new value is added simply add it to your total amount and put the new value in the TextView

```
totalAmount += 40;
textView.setText(totalAmount + "$");
```

that should do the trick :)